# Prevent jquery event if mouseleave function is still active

Tags: jquery

I have a list of div's, which on mouse enter / leave triggers a function. I'm trying to prevent the other div's from triggering their enter functions till the last entered div has finished its leaving function. Currently when entering 'hovering' multiple div's it triggers all their functions instantly. Any help/support on this would be appreciated, thank you.

**JS**

```
  project.mouseenter(function() {
    var position = project_position++;
    var colourDuration = 1000, colourDelay = 500;
    $(this).find('.colour-block').velocity({left:'100%'},{duration: colourDuration, delay: colourDelay});
  });
  project.mouseleave(function() {
    var position = project_position++;
    var colourDuration = 1000, colourDelay = 500;
    $(this).find('.colour-block').velocity({left:0},{duration: colourDuration, delay: colourDelay});
  });
```

**HTML**

```
        <!-- Project (1) -->
        <div class="project xxx">
          <div class="colour-block"></div>
          <div class="content-block">
            <div class="center-vertically">
              <h2><a href="project.html">xxx</a></h2>
              <p><a href="project.html">Morbi scelerisque id ante vulputate cursus.</a></p>
              <button>&#8594;</button>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#" title="Brand">Brand</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title-="Digital">Digital</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Graphic">Graphic</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Project (2) -->
        <div class="project xxx">
          <div class="colour-block"></div>
          <div class="content-block">
            <div class="center-vertically">
              <h2><a href="project.html">xxx</a></h2>
              <p><a href="project.html">Morbi scelerisque id ante vulputate cursus.</a></p>
              <button>&#8594;</button>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#" title="Brand">Brand</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title-="Digital">Digital</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Graphic">Graphic</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Project (3) -->
        <div class="project xxx">
          <div class="colour-block"></div>
          <div class="content-block">
            <div class="center-vertically">
              <h2><a href="project.html">xxx</a></h2>
              <p><a href="project.html">Morbi scelerisque id ante vulputate cursus.</a></p>
              <button>&#8594;</button>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#" title="Brand">Brand</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title-="Digital">Digital</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Graphic">Graphic</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: create an animation stack array and use velocity completion callback to check if anything in stack to animate. Or cancel prior animations as you enter new element

Comment: Then a stack array would be best approach. Neither answer below is well thought out

Comment: How would I go around developing a stack array ? Do you know of any documentation on this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var hasEntered=false;

project.mouseenter(function() {
    if(!hasEntered){    
        var position = project_position++;
        var colourDuration = 1000, colourDelay = 500;
        $(this).find('.colour-block').velocity({left:'100%'},{duration: colourDuration, delay: colourDelay});
        hasEntered=true;
    }
});
project.mouseleave(function() {
    if(hasEntered){
        var position = project_position++;
        var colourDuration = 1000, colourDelay = 500;
        $(this).find('.colour-block').velocity({left:0},{duration: colourDuration, delay: colourDelay});
        hasEntered=false;
    }
});
```

may be you can use a flag to prevent mousenter to fire.

Comment: I've implemented this, but when you hover the next div it doesn't trigger the event till you hover out and in on the div.

Comment: you have mouseenter and mouseleave events using velocity.js to do some animation, do you need mouseenter animation to only execute when mouseleave animation has finished?